# How can I remove a cell.imageView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm wondering why I didn't found anything about removen a imageView within a cell completely. I've worked with the hidden-property, but the area of the image before is still there, so I can not overwrite it completely.

Is there a simple way of removing an cell.imageView completely?

Maybe it is a simple question, but I didn't found a solution so far :-/

Comment: `cell.imageView.image = nil;` removes any image and hides the image view. What exactly do you want to do? Also, you should try improving your accept-rate, 40% is pretty bad.

Comment: @DougAmos please post your problem as a new question instead of commenting on a 5-year old one,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `[cell.imageView removeFromSuperview];` ?

or if you want to just remove the image:

```
cell.imageView.image = nil;
```